# 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH' while decryption in node js

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, aes, node-crypto

I have used AES encryption in java as below and trying to decrypt in javascript

JAVA :

```
    byte[] input = "data".getBytes();       
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] thedigest = md.digest("ENCRYPTION_KEY".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    SecretKeySpec skc = new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOf(thedigest, 16), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skc);
    
    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
    int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
    ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
        
    String encryptData = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
    // Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);

    System.out.println("encryptString:.......... "+encryptData);
```

NODEJS:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
let keyStr = "ENCRYPTION_KEY";
var text = 'infodba';
var hashPwd =crypto.createHash('sha256').update(keyStr,'utf8').digest();
var key=[] ;
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  key[i] = hashPwd[i];
}
var keyBuffer = new Buffer(hashPwd);
var decipherIV = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ecb', keyBuffer,'');
var cipherTxtBuffer = new Buffer('encryptedData','hex');
var output = decipherIV.update(cipherTxtBuffer);
output= output+decipherIV.final();
console.log("Dec Output "+output);
```

While running the node JS code getting error

internal/crypto/cipher.js:174
const ret = this[kHandle].final();                     ^

Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
at Decipheriv.final (internal/crypto/cipher.js:174:29)
at deciphers (D:\TestJS\index.js:32:30)

Answer (score 1):

The Java code uses only the first 16 bytes of the SHA256 hash as key, so the hash has to be truncated accordingly:

```js
var keyStr = 'ENCRYPTION_KEY';
var hashPwd = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(keyStr, 'utf8').digest();
var keyBuffer = Buffer.from(hashPwd.subarray(0, 16));
```

A 16 bytes key corresponds to AES-128, so `'aes-128-ecb'` has to be used for decryption (and not `'aes-256-ecb'`). Furthermore, the ciphertext is Base64url encoded, so it has to be Base64url decoded (and not hex decoded):

```js
var encryptedData = 'dkcvstQcGMQUJ1EJbHs3eY6j_0DjWqYTDGmedmUZwWs=';
var decipherIV = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-ecb', keyBuffer,'');
var output = Buffer.concat([decipherIV.update(encryptedData, 'base64url'), decipherIV.final()]);
```

`output` is a buffer and may have to be UTF-8 decoded:

```js
console.log(output.toString('utf8')); // §3.1: The fee is $3,000.
```

With these changes, the NodeJS code decrypts the ciphertext created with the Java code.

---

Security:

- The ECB mode is insecure and should not be used. Nowadays authenticated encryption is usually applied (such as GCM), or at least a mode with an IV (such as CBC).
- Using a (fast) digest like SHA256 as key derivation is insecure. More secure is a dedicated key derivation function like Argon2 or PBKDF2.
- In the Java code, the `Cipher` object is instantiated with the algorithm (`"AES"`) alone. This is not robust because then the provider-dependent default values are applied for mode and padding. For SunJCE, these are ECB and PKCS#5 padding, to which the NodeJS code is tailored. For other providers this may differ, so that the NodeJS code would then no longer be compatible. Therefore, it should be fully specified, e.g. `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"`.
- Similarly, when encoding the plaintext with `getBytes()`, the encoding should be specified, otherwise the platform-dependent default encoding is used.